# Noise Cancellation Filter w/ MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, noise

I have an input signal:

```
x[n] = sin(pi/10*n) * (u[n] - u[n-10])
```

and an impulse response:

```
h[n] = 0.9^n * u[n] + delta(n)
```

representing the echo of the system.  So I'm trying to design an echo cancelation filter, but it doesn't seem right.  I think I'm making a mistake using the delta function.  Anyway, I find the DTFT, it's reciprocal, and then the IDTFT:

```
g[n] = dirac[n] - 1/2(0.45^n u[n])
```

So if I convolve y[n] = x[n] * h[n], and then convolve v[n] = y[n] * g[n], shouldn't I get my original signal x[n] back?  I also tried not using the dirac delta function and just made a vector with 1 at zero and zero elsewhere, but that didn't work either.  Where did I go wrong?  Thanks for looking

MATLAB Code:

```
n = -10:0.1:10;
% input signal
x = sin(pi/10 * n) .* (heaviside(n) - heaviside(n-10));
% echo
h = 0.9 .^ n .* heaviside(n) + dirac(n);
% echo cancelation
g = dirac(n) - 0.5 * (0.45.^n) .* heaviside(n);
% convolutions
y = conv(x,h);
v = conv(y,g);
% plots
figure(1)
stem(x)
figure(2)
stem(y)
figure(3)
stem(v)
```

Comment: you sure you are doing what you want? dirac(n) is inserting you a INF in you numbers. I know diracs is like that, not sure if Matlab handles that correctly.

Comment: what is y supposed to be? is H the echo or the behaviour of the system with the echo? If it is the behaviour (as it has more sense) y is the echo after the sound. does it have sense? Also, why don't you work in Laplace space? it is better for this kind of things, In my opinion.